# Ajax calendar extender start date and end date differ by 60 Days

Tags: javascript, ajax, datepicker

I am using 2 ajax calender extender

1) Start Date
2) End Date.

I want end date should be 60 days ahead from start date.

My Date format from calender extender is 08-May-2014 (dd-MMM-yyyy)

Code :

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox" runat="server"      onchange="javascript:EndDateTimeEndDate();" Width="100px" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="EFF_START_DATEDVCalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy">
```

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EFF_END_DATEDVTextBox" onchange="javascript:EndDateTimeEndDate();" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="EFF_END_DATEDVCalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="EFF_END_DATEDVTextBox" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy">                                                           </ajax:CalendarExtender>
</div>
```

like say for example when I select start date, the end date should be 60 Days ahead from start date vice versa..

I am trying to do in the following way but it's fail in converting the date time.

```
 function EndDateTimeEndDate() {

            var datestart = new Date(document.getElementById('<%=EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value)
            var dateEnd = new Date(document.getElementById('<%=EFF_END_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value)
            alert(datestart);
            document.getElementById('<%=EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value = datestart + 60

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
document.getElementById('<%=EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value = datestart.getDate() - 60;
```

**EDIT:**

```
    var startdate = new Date(document.getElementById('<%=EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value);
    var EndDate= new Date();
    EndDate.setDate(startdate .getDate() + 60);
    alert(EndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer

```
function StartDateTimeEndDate1() 
                { 
                        var startDate = document.getElementById('<%=EFF_START_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value
                        var arrstartdate = startDate.split('-');
                        var newdate = arrstartdate[0] + ' ' + arrstartdate[1] + ' ' + arrstartdate[2] 
                        var actualDate = new Date(newdate); // convert to actual date
                        var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate() + 60); // create new increased date 
                        // now extract the bits we want to crete the text version of the new date..
                        var newDateString = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).substr(-2) + '-' + newDate.toDateString().substr(4, 3) + '-' + newDate.getFullYear();
                        var charstr = newDateString.split('-')
                        if (charstr[0].length == 3) 
                        {
                              document.getElementById('<%=EFF_END_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value = newDateString.substr(1)
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                             document.getElementById('<%=EFF_END_DATEDVTextBox.ClientID %>').value = newDateString 
                        } 
                }
```